# Isotope initialization won't work. Having issues with images after adding slick.js carousel plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a grid using Desandro's Isotope.js and it's working fine until I added [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), a carousel plugin of my choice.

Now, on load,  the images that I put inside the carousel seems to go outside the .item container of isotope as block and that leaves a gap messing up the grid. When I press the responsive view from Firefox, it seems that the grids re-shuffles and it displays the correct positioning of the grid again.

[image]

So I thought it may be in the initialization of the script. I tried to put the isotope script at the bottom after the slick.js initialization with no effect. When I tried the $(document).ready function, isotope won't work anymore.

Changing the height from auto to fixed height on `.carousel-item` gets rid of the gap but the thing is I made the isotope responsive so when viewing it on other size screen, the grids aren't equal again  (the height of the .carousel-item gets smaller than the rest of the grid making the grid uneven on smaller screens).

My HTML is something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>

    <div class="item h2 w3">
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div><img src="http://placeholdit.300x300"></div>
          <div><img src="http://placeholdit.300x300"></div>
          <div><img src="http://placeholdit.300x300"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item h2"></div>
    <div class="item w3"></div>
    <div class="item w2"></div>
</div>
```

this is my initialization that works good but with the grid messed up after adding images on slick.js carousel

```
var $container = $('#container');
// init
$container.isotope({
  // options
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
  },
  itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

I am trying to add this after googling isotope initialization but isotope doesn't work at all with this script.

```
$(document).ready({
  $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
    $container.isotope({
      // options
      masonry: {
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
      },
      itemSelector: '.item'
    })
  }
})
```

this doesn't work either

```
 var $container = $('#container').imagesLoaded( function() {
    $container.isotope({
     // options
     masonry: {
       columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
       gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
     },
     itemSelector: '.item'
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

```
    var $container = $('.l-grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.block',
            gutter: 0,
            transitionDuration: 0,
            layoutMode: 'packery'
        });
    });
```

And it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your slick code BEFORE the isotope init.